# Can already-retired immigrants get Social Security or other payments from the U.S. government?

Tags: united-states, retirement, pension, social-security

My parents are 83+, and became U.S. citizens back in 2001. They were born as Indian citizens. They moved to the USA after they retired in India. Will they be entitled to receive any monthly payments from the U.S. Government, such as Social Security or other pension/benefit payments? Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 9):

No. Regardless of citizenship, you need to have paid into the social security system for 10 years or more to be eligible to collect a retirement benefit. This is measured in the form of "credits" -- you earn one credit for each quarter of a year that you work. You need 40 credits to earn a retirement.

If they are deemed to be disabled or have a qualifying medical condition, they may be eligible for SSI or SSDI.